# Обращение внутри hendler к элементу, активировавшему click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть необходимость привязать обработчик ко всем элементам одного класса. При этом обработчик должен работать только с дочерними элементами элемента, вызвавшего событие.

Делаю примерно так:

```js
$('.select').click(
    function(ev) { 
        ev.target.find('.subselect').toggle() 
    }
)
```

Но получаю ошибку, что `find` не является функцией. Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что свойство `target` объекта события содержит информацию об элементе DOM, а не JQuery-объект, поэтому функция `find` считается необъявленной для данного класса.

Как в таком случае внутри хендлера обращаться к элементу, вызвавшему обрабатываемое событие?

Comment: оберните в jQuery объект `ev.target`

Comment: типа так?: `$(ev.target).find()`

Comment: Да, типа так...

Comment: или так: $(this).find('.subselect').toggle()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [frozencoast](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/387045/frozencoast) за помощь в [комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1136660/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-hendler-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-click?noredirect=1#comment1966161_1136660).

Правильный вариант:

```js
$('.select').click(
    function(ev) { 
        $(this).find('.subselect').toggle() 
    }
)
```